# Explain the water pouring ceremony of Samuel

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, samuel-shmuel-book-of, water

In 1 Samuel 7:6 as part of the repentance of the nation the people draw and pour out water. Many commentators explain this as being symbolic of obeisance as if their are pouring out their hearts. My question is where does any of this come from? The Torah has clear parameters for repentance and forgiveness, of which the people avail themselves including sacrifice, fasting and prayer. Why was a seemingly new ceremonial act employed? Where did it come from and if it fact has meaning why is it not employed at other times?

Comment: Targum yonasan per rashi (and the yerushalmi) understand this allegorically; they didn't actually spill any water. The malbim has a different explanation, and says it means they cried. Do these answer your question, or do you want an answer specifically according to the understanding that they actually spilled water, as a sign of teshuva?

Comment: Also, the radak quotes a passuk in iyov as a (sort of) source for this, but I'm not sure that helps either, seeing as its not clear which was written first

Comment: @Loani specifically according to the plain meaning of the text

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much